# api key of openweathermap in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api-key, openweathermap

I have written a weather app by using API of [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/) (free account) in React. I have used fetch in componentDidMount like this.

```
async componentDidMount()
  {
    const url1 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=Hanoi,VN&appid=" + api_key;
    const today = await GetData(url1);
    const url2 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?units=metric&q=Hanoi,VN&appid=" + api_key;
    const forecast = await GetData(url2);
    this.setState({
      data: today,
      forecast: forecast
    });
```

Considering my API key has been blocked once because of using it on more than 60 requests in a minute. Hence I have a question, if someone spams reload on my webpage,

1. Will it call componentDidMount each time a reload happens?
2. How can I prevent this?

Comment: ComponentDidMount calls only ones when we load the component

Comment: If people reload webpage, won't it reload the component ?

Comment: yes, it will be called on reload

Comment: I have just tried to spam reload on my webpage until it reached limit, but my api_key wasn't blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentDidMount will be called every time a page is reloaded.

Please read about the component life cycle methods in details in official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle. I don't think you can prevent componentDidMount from getting called on page reload. Because this is how it works.

However, you may make a call to openweatherapp from your server and use IP based throttling to prevent DoS attack on your server.

Comment: i have tried to spam reload on my webpage more than 60 times in one minute but my api_key wasn't blocked

Comment: Are you sure that each of those reloads happened successfully? I doubt that. Even if they happened successfully there is a chance to get detected by openweathermap, this is purely dependent on how they have restricted access to their APIs.

Comment: Yes, each time my componentDidMount will make two calls to the api, so I just need to reload more than 30 times. At the first time, it rendered slowly, but everytime after that, it immediately rendered everything so fast.

Comment: However, thank you every much for your help Lokesh Agrawal

Comment: Happy to help :)